# Ignore undefined data in MySQL UPDATE with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I developed CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) App with nodejs. But I have some problem in Update Function.

```
/* POST Update Page */
router.post(
  "/:userId/:pageId/update_process",
  upload.single("projectImg"),
  function(req, res) {
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let pageId = req.params.pageId;
    db.query(`SELECT imgurl FROM Personal_Data WHERE id=?`, [pageId], function(
      error,
      data
    ) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      console.log(data[0]);
      let checkImage = data[0];

      let name = req.body.projectName;
      let type = req.body.portType;
      let url = req.body.projectUrl;
      let explanation = req.body.projectExplanation;

      let imgurl = req.file.filename;
      let sumlang = req.body.sumLang;
      let pjdate1 = req.body.pjdate1;
      let pjdate2 = req.body.pjdate2;
      let githuburl = req.body.githuburl;

      // If Imgurl is undefined
      if (imgurl === undefined) {
        db.query(
          `UPDATE Personal_Data SET name=?, type=?, url=?, explanation=?, sumlang=?, pjdate1=?, pjdate2=?, githuburl=? WHERE id=?`,
          [
            name,
            type,
            url,
            explanation,
            sumlang,
            pjdate1,
            pjdate2,
            githuburl,
            pageId
          ]
        );
        // If Imgurl is exist
      } else {
        db.query(
          `UPDATE Personal_Data SET name=?, type=?, url=?, explanation=?, imgurl=?, sumlang=?, pjdate1=?, pjdate2=?, githuburl=? WHERE id=?`,
          [
            name,
            type,
            url,
            explanation,
            imgurl,
            sumlang,
            pjdate1,
            pjdate2,
            githuburl,
            pageId
          ]
        );
      }
    });

    res.redirect("/" + userId);
  }
);
```

All functions works fine but in imgurl part is not working properly. It's a update page so I get all the previous data from DB.So Update page looks like this

[image]

In file upload button the default data is null and if I update the with different image, it works fine. But I want to make it If I do not specify a new image file, I just want to use the old data as it is.

But If the file exist it works but if it's not exist it gives me an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
```

Comment: How is `multer` configured? `filename` is only available if you're using [`DiskStorage`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information), for instance.

Comment: @robertklep In multer it configured with DiskStorage so that I can use filename. But It only not works when the file is not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
let imgurl = req.file ? req.file.filename : undefined;
```

In other words: if the user didn't upload a file, `imgurl` should be undefined, otherwise it should contain the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now.!! :) I forgot about the conditional ternary operator.